# Errors using TCHAR,cannot convert to wchar_t

Tags: c++, wchar-t, tchar

I've been asked to add functionality to an existing old project but i cannot get it to build.
It handles unicode strings but i get a lot of errors regarding the use of TCHAR.Specifically almost every error is TCHAR cannot be converted to or used as wchar_t.
From what i saw on many different articles i tried using #define _UNICODE or #define UNICODE but none of them solved the problem.

Here is a piece of the code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <cctype>
#include <winnt.h>
#include <atlconv.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"wininet.lib")

using namespace std;

TCHAR *tags[] = { _T("aa"), _T("bb"), _T("cc"),
NULL };

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{


int i = 0;


for (i = 1; i<argc; i++) { 
    if (wcscmp(argv[i], _T("-h")) == 0) {
        ...
    }
    else if (wcscmp(argv[i], _T("-f")) == 0) {
        ...
    }


...
}
```

In the above lines for example,when using wcscmp, i get

```
    argument of type "_TCHAR *" is incompatible with parameter of type "const wchar_t *"
```

regarding the   argv[i]

and

```
    argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "const wchar_t *"
```

regarding the _T("-h").

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The code has been written to target Unicode rather than MBCS. This can be discerned by the use of `wcscmp` which accepts parameters of type `const wchar_t*`.

On the other hand, there are parts of the code which use `TCHAR` and related macros. Now, [`TCHAR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c426s321.aspx) is a macro that resolves to either `char` or `wchar_t` depending on whether or not `_UNICODE` or `_MBCS` are defined. Consult the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c426s321.aspx) for more details.

The use of `TCHAR` stems from the days when developers wished to write code for both Windows NT/2000 (which supported both ANSI and Unicode APIs), and Windows 95/98 (which has only ANSI APIs). The use of `TCHAR` allowed a common code base. Compile with `_UNICODE` defined for NT/2000, and compile with `_MBCS` defined for 95/98.

If you code in this style then you write `_tcscmp` rather than `wcscmp`. For a Unicode build it resolves `wcscmp`, and for an MBCS build it resolves to `_mbscmp`.

These days you typically do not need to write code to support 95/98. You can probably choose to neglect those platforms. In which case you should target Unicode and stop using `TCHAR` and related macros. Replace `_T("..")` with `L".."`. Replace `tmain` with `wmain`. Replace `TCHAR` with `wchar_t`. And so on.

You don't need to make these changes. You could simply target Unicode and your code will compile. However, the `TCHAR` idiom has been applied inconsistently in your code base. Note the use of `_tmain`, `TCHAR`, but also the calls to `wcscmp`. So your code cannot compile unless it targets Unicode. So you are losing nothing by abandoning `TCHAR`. What you gain is clarity. You get to stop using these macros and avoid all the obfuscation that they provide. Indirection is a great tool, but if it is not needed then it simply leads to confusion and obfuscation.

Comment: very nice answer!i was actually wondering if this kind of coding was actually necessary.thanks david!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're not building your application for Unicode, so check your project settings.

If you're using the wide string functions like `wcscmp` then there's no point in using the `_T()` macro as your come will fail to compile when compiled in non-Unicode mode. If you want the code to compile in both modes when you need to use the `TCHAR` aware functions in `<tchar.h>` such as [_tcscmp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0z9k731.aspx) .

If you always want a string to be wide then place an `L` at the from, eg `L"Hello, world"`

Comment: thanks for your help.changing the settings solves the problem,so i was wondering regarding what you said is there any case that i'd want to compile in non-Unicode mode?

Comment: @yiannis I've tried to address that in my answer. I think you should do more than just switch to Unicode targeting. I think you should get rid of the confusing `TCHAR` idiom that has been used inconsistently.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio, set *Character Set* to *Use Unicode Character Set* under project *Configuration Properties*.

I think you could use #define UNICODE, but make sure to do it before any includes.