# Using GetCurrentDirectory with wcstombs

Tags: c, windows, winapi, tchar

I got a code from collegaue that was written a time ago, and is confusing.
The code is:

```
TCHAR Curr_dir[100];  
char* input_file;  
DWORD a = GetCurrentDirectory(100, Curr_dir);  
size_t i= wcstombs(&input_file[i], Curr_dir, 100);
```

The problem is that `Curr_dir` is not the type that needed to `wcstombs`.
Is there any other functions that can do what `wcstombs` does with this type of variable?
Or a way to convert it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Errors using TCHAR,cannot convert to wchar\_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257851/errors-using-tchar-cannot-convert-to-wchar-t) - also, this seems like a C question.

Comment: @kabanus Though, the Win32 API is a C API it is prepared for / used in C++ as well. The questioner probably writes a C++ program. Thus, let him go this time... (Btw. thanks for the link - I "liked" the accepted answer.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a code that once supported multi-byte and UNICODE but decayed after stopped being compiled for multi-byte (no more supporting Windows 95).

This code snipped makes sense only if you have `_UNICODE` defined. In this case it end like this after the pre-processor:

```
wchar_t Curr_dir[100];  
char* input_file;  
unsigned long a = GetCurrentDirectoryW(100, Curr_dir);  
size_t i= wcstombs(&input_file[i], Curr_dir, 100);
```

In this case the [`GetCurrentDirectoryW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934(v=vs.85).aspx) returns a UINCODE (wide string) in `Curr_dir` and it's converted, for some whatever reason, to a multi-byte string. And the types of the chars match.

But if `_UNICODE` is *not* defined it the code changes to the following:

```
char Curr_dir[100];  
char* input_file;  
unsigned long a = GetCurrentDirectoryA(100, Curr_dir);  
size_t i= wcstombs(&input_file[i], Curr_dir, 100);
```

And `GetCurrentDirectoryA` now switches to the [ANSI version of the API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374089(v=vs.85).aspx) it makes no sense to call `wcstombs` anymore.

Usually the MDSN documentation has a section with a table with all versions of a string function under **Generic-Text Routine Mappings** ( for example [`strcmp-wcscmp-mbscmp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strcmp-wcscmp-mbscmp)) There is no '_t' version of the [`wcstombs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/wcsrtombs) so you need to use `#ifdef _UNICODE`.

But even if the the multi-byte version of the Win32 API may be still supported it makes no sense to keep using them.

More: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/76252/what-are-tchar-wchar-lpstr-lpwstr-lpctstr-etc